# Is it possible to run cloud build using rest api with passing substitutions variables?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to run cloud build config.json using rest api.
I managed to run a simple config.json, but mine has substitution variable that I wish to pass and replace in my rest api request.
Is there a way to do so with rest api?
I know it's possible with gcloud but I don't want to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) documentation, to use **substitution variables** you need to use the gcloud command and pass all the respective values with the --substitutions argument.

If you are using the REST API you could probably just parse these variables when creating the JSON request body, I am not sure why substitution variables would be needed.

If you are unsure about how the APIs work, I recommend checking [Google’s API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/cloudbuild/v1/cloudbuild.projects.builds.create), it even gives you hints about each available parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I have a config.json in my repository that is creating the whole CD. I don't want to edit it everytime I need to run it, since I'm not the only one using it. Each one of the developers can create his own env, so different parameters are needed. For now as a workaround I have a function that executes the build which can receive params.

Comment: Unless you are using the default substitution variables, you would need to manually set the value of any user-defined variables you want to use.
I am not sure about how you intend to call the API, but I was able to create a script that makes a JSON request body, using the structure of a config.json file, and takes the value of the _EXAMPLE_USER_VARIABLE before calling the API. 
This example [GitHub link](https://github.com/Victor-Pessolato/cloud-build-with-substitution-variables/blob/master/json-request-bash.sh) runs a simple build that just prints the value of my user-defined variable.

Comment: thanks again. but my question is how do you pass the value of  _EXAMPLE_USER_VARIABLE to the config.json from the curl request.

Comment: Since user-defined variables require you to set their values manually in the “substitutions” parameter, it would not be possible to dynamically pass these values using a static config.json, you could use it as a template, but the data of the request body would need to be built before calling the API. If you are working with bash, the example I sent before would be a possible workaround, as it is a script that stores the JSON string in a variable, setting the custom values through concatenation before calling the API with the curl command.